# Duplicate messages between connected servers using hyperswarm library

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, stdin, p2p

I am trying to send a message from one connected node server to the other using the following code in `server.js` and `server1.js`:

```
const hyperswarm = require('hyperswarm')
const crypto = require('crypto')

const swarm = hyperswarm()

// look for peers listed under this topic
const topic = crypto.createHash('sha256')
  .update('mycoolstuff')
  .digest()

swarm.join(topic, {
  lookup: true, // find & connect to peers
  announce: true // optional- announce self as a connection target
})

swarm.on('connection', (socket, details) => {
  //console.log('new connection!', details)

  // you can now use the socket as a stream, eg:
  process.stdin.pipe(socket).pipe(process.stdout)
})
```

The problem is the message from one terminal is duplicated on the other.

For example, if I type the following in server.js's terminal:

```
test 123
```

I get the following in server1.js's:

```
test 123
test 123
```

. . . and vice versa

I can work around this by setting one of the two servers to not announce:

```
swarm.join(topic, {
  lookup: true, // find & connect to peers
  announce: false // <--------- don't announce, stops duplicates
})
```

But I would prefer that both servers announce.

What am I misunderstanding about sockets, stdin, or hyperswarm here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found my own answer inside the node module folder for hyperswarm in the file called `example.js`

I added the following:

```
  const {
    priority,
    status,
    retries,
    peer,
    client
  } = details

  if (client) process.stdin.pipe(socket)
  else socket.pipe(process.stdout)
```

Which solved my problem.